# FormClosing and FormClosed events do not work

Tags: c#, forms, events

I'm developing a `C#` app
And i need do some validations before the user close the form.

I tried to use the `FormClosing` event, but it didn't work,
later I used the `FormClosed` event, but the same.

The problem is, when I click in the "close button" (on the top of the form) it doesn't do anything but i have the events in form properties and everything.

[image]
[image]

this is my code:

```
    private void Inicio_FormClosing_1(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
    //things I have to do
    //...
    //...

    if(bandera==true)
    Application.Exit();

    }
```

and

```
    private void Inicio_FormClosed_1(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
    //things I have to do
    //...
    //...

    if(bandera==true)
    Application.Exit();

    }
```

**any idea?**

Thank you

Comment: Note that the expression `if(bandera=true)` is almost certainly wrong.  You're *assigning` true to `bandera` and then returning true.  You probably meant to write: `if(bandera==true)` instead, although you can simplify it to just `if(bandera)`, since any boolean value compared to `true` will always return itself.  Depending on how you're observing the behavior, that may or may not be your actual problem.

Comment: @Jean: set a break point in start of function and see it's event catch it!

Comment: @Servy I edited it! sorry (but it's not the problem)

Comment: @IRSOG I did it. the application completely omitted these code lines

Comment: @Jean, what does it say in your `Ignicio.Designer.cs` file?  You should be able to see a line of code in there that looks like this: `this.FormClosing += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventHandler(this.Ignicio_FormClosing_1);`  (You may have to expand the `Windows Form Designer generated code` region to see it.)

Comment: `this.FormClosing += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventHandler(this.Inicio_FormClosing_1);` @Brian Rogers I don't think it's the problem

Comment: I found my mistake than you @Brian I deleted the line `InitializeComponent();` by mistake

Comment: @Jean Glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**I found the mistake;**

Here: (when I initialize my form)

```
    public Inicio()
    {
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.AutoScroll = true;

        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(635, 332);
        this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        llenaForm(nombreFormulario);
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();

    }
```

All i needed was:             `InitializeComponent();`
I deleted by mistake

It should be:

```
    public Inicio()
    {
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.AutoScroll = true;`

        InitializeComponent();//<<<<<<<<------------------- 

        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(635, 332);
        this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        llenaForm(nombreFormulario);
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    }
```

**Thank you so much guys!**

Answer (score 5):

Both events should work fine. Just open a new project and do this simple test:

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     this.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(Inicio_FormClosing_1);
     this.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(Inicio_FormClosed_1);
 }

 private void Inicio_FormClosing_1(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
 {
     //Things while closing

 }

 private void Inicio_FormClosed_1(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
 {
     //Things when closed
 }
```

If you set break points in these methods, you would see that they are reached after the close button is clicked. It seems that there is some problem in your event-attaching code. For example: `Inicio_FormClosed_1(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)` is wrong, as far as it should take a `FormClosedEventArgs` argument; and thus this method is surely not associated with the `FormClosed event` (otherwise, the code wouldn't compile).

Comment: I did it, **and It works!**, but id doesn't work in my app. why? @varocarbas

Comment: @Jean This is what I don't understand either (haven't ever have a problem while dealing with these events; I usually deal with FormClosing, as suggested above). Look at the part of your code where you are attaching the events and see what might be wrong.

Comment: It works because this is the code that links your methods to the FormClosingEventHandler.  This is normally not done in the form load.  Usually, you do this in the UI via the properties window. @jean

Answer (score 3):

In order to prevent the user from closing a form in response to certain validations, you need to set `FormClosingEventArgs.Cancel = true`.

For example:

```
private void Inicio_FormClosing_1(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSomethingRequired.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Something is required here!");
        if (txtSomethingRequired.CanFocus) txtSomethingRequired.Focus();
        e.Cancel = true;
        return;
    }
}
```

You can only do validations in the `FormClosing` event to prevent the form from closing; if you wait until `FormClosed` it is already too late.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed you have an "_1" at the end of your method names.  Did you rename these methods?

If so, your UI code(designer file) will need to be updated with these new method names.

You can put a breakpoint in these methods to see if they are getting called.

Comment: **I have some breakpoints but these methods are not called @L_7337 OR are  completely omitted**

Comment: My guess would be either that Application.Exit() is getting called OR the FormClosing event handler is not getting linked properly.

Comment: With the Form highlighted, goto the Properties Windows and click the lightning bolt. Go down to FormClosing and make sure that this is Inicio_FormClosing_1 exactly.

Comment: It's okay, but the problem continues @L_7337

Answer (score 0):

Just as a side note, the Form.Hide() method does not raised the form_closed or form_closing events

Answer (score 0):

I also faced a similar problem, and it was provoked by using `Dispose()`.
Make sure that you are using `Close()` to raise closing/closed events.

Answer (score 0):

The same for me if calling END in VB.net the FormClosing will not fire. Had to use Me.Close() to get the event to fire.